# Solving quadratic congruence

Tags: r, quadratic

I want to solve this equation x^2= 4 mod 3 in R, I tried many commands but that commands are not related to this equation. Please help me to find the command.
For example, I tried

```
modlin(2,4,3)
# [1] 2

modpower(2,4,3)
# [1] 1
```

and five other commands.

Comment: this should help you. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-November/082164.html

Comment: can you give more insight on what would be the input data and in what format do you need the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self-made function that solves x^2=n mod m:

```
f <- function(n,m){which(((0:(m-1))^2 %% m)==(n %% m))[1] - 1}
```

.

```
> f(4,3)
[1] 1
> sapply(-10:10,f,5)
 [1]  0  1 NA NA  2  0  1 NA NA  2  0  1 NA NA  2  0  1 NA NA  2  0
>
```